# Cannot create parmetarized procedure in mariadb

Tags: sql, mariadb

This gives a syntax error, how can i fix it?

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS mydb.getInfo;

DELIMITER $$
$$
CREATE PROCEDURE mydb.getInfo(in eid)
BEGIN
    SELECT seller_name FROM seller WHERE seller_id = eid;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: which  syntax error?

Comment: All it says:-   you have a syntax error in line 1 check mariadb manual for correct syntax.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.